# Finding asymptote

Tags: functions, asymptotics

[image]

Do i just set $a=1$?

$\frac{\left(2x^2-3x+1\right)}{x-2} = \frac{\left(2x-1\right)\left(x-1\right)}{x-1}$  then the answer would be 2x-1, and got no vertical asymptotes for vertical and horizontal

Answer (score 1):

Also talk about the case when $ a= 1/2.$ In that case there is no vertical asymptote like $a= 1$ case. For any other value of $a$, there is a vertical asymptote at $x =a.$.

Conclusion: No vertical asymptote for $a = 1, 1/2.$ There is a vertical asymptote for any other $a$ values.